# Using webpack to make firebase the primary "dependancy" file for the rest of our website

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, webpack

So I am using webpack to try and make a website, and I want to make my firebase be an entry point that my main javascript file (and the files following) will depend on so that firebase is loaded before the rest of the files

here is what I have:

module.exports = {

```
mode: 'development',
entry: {
    firebase: './mainPage/firebase.js',
    main: {
        import:'./mainPage/main.js',
        dependOn: 'firebase.js'
    }, 
    
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist'
},
watch: true
```

};

I am unsure if

1. this is the correct way to set up the entry points correctly
2. if this is the best way to make sure firebase is handled correctly

This is my groups first time handling the creation of websites,so we are super lost in research and what we are doing. So sorry if this question is not phrased correctly or vague.